# Liferay 7.2/7.3 error: 'PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP'

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, adoptopenjdk, azul-zulu

When using the bundled version of Liferay 7.2 or 7.3 with Java version 11.0.6 (the Azul Zulu build, also happens with AdoptOpenJDK), I get the following error in the log file and can't sign in or see portlets. When clicking on 'Sign In', there is an error 'Sign In is temporarily unavailable.' preventing any login to the portal.

```
2020-03-05 11:23:05.743 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:304] Unable to dispatch request: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
2020-03-05 11:23:05.747 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10][PortletServlet:119] javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:307)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:572)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:588)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:462)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:291)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.render(MVCPortlet.java:304)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:127)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:124)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:115)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:571)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:661)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:344)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.lambda$render$0(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:259)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet._render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:363)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:257)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl$IndirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl.java:190)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:79)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.TransferHeadersHelperImpl$TransferHeadersRequestDispatcher.include(TransferHeadersHelperImpl.java:162)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._render(PortletContainerImpl.java:908)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.lambda$render$2(PortletContainerImpl.java:223)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:425)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:211)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:145)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.lambda$render$0(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:128)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper._render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:189)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:401)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:170)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:415)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:155)
    at com.liferay.portal.internal.servlet.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:205)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at com.liferay.portal.internal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:124)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:183)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at com.liferay.friendly.url.internal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:409)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:124)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:368)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:87)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:264)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:249)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:147)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:183)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:655)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:291)
    ... 160 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: entry
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:163)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.JspCompiler.compile(JspCompiler.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:384)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.CompilerWrapper.compile(CompilerWrapper.java:74)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:645)
    ... 171 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: entry
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:372)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.zip.ZipFileUtil.openInputStream(ZipFileUtil.java:36)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.JarJavaFileObject.openInputStream(JarJavaFileObject.java:39)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$WrappedFileObject.openInputStream(ClientCodeWrapper.java:592)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassFile(ClassReader.java:2820)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:359)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.complete(ClassFinder.java:291)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1326)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.loadClass(ClassFinder.java:433)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.loadClass(Resolve.java:1996)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInPackageInternal(Resolve.java:2386)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInPackage(Resolve.java:2374)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java:3716)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3601)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2114)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:655)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:715)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:708)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$ImportsPhase.attribImportType(TypeEnter.java:441)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$ImportsPhase.doImport(TypeEnter.java:424)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$ImportsPhase.resolveImports(TypeEnter.java:364)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$ImportsPhase.runPhase(TypeEnter.java:321)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.doCompleteEnvs(TypeEnter.java:282)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.completeEnvs(TypeEnter.java:251)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter.complete(TypeEnter.java:198)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1326)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:583)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:560)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1066)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:937)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
    ... 178 more
2020-03-05 11:23:05.771 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10][render_portlet_jsp:131] null
java.lang.NullPointerException: entry
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:372)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.zip.ZipFileUtil.openInputStream(ZipFileUtil.java:36)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.jsp.compiler.internal.JarJavaFileObject.openInputStream(JarJavaFileObject.java:39)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$WrappedFileObject.openInputStream(ClientCodeWrapper.java:592)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassFile(ClassReader.java:2820)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:359)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.complete(ClassFinder.java:291)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1326)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.loadClass(ClassFinder.java:433)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.loadClass(Resolve.java:1996)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInPackageInternal(Resolve.java:2386)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInPackage(Resolve.java:2374)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java:3716)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3601)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2114)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:655)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:715)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:708)
```

Any idea why this is happening and how it can be resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember that there was some problem with an 11.0.6 build of some JDK - you might run into it. Try an earlier - my memory seems to recall a recommendation of 11.0.4.

If that one works, try to update again once newer versions are out.

Sorry, I can't give any references right now

Comment: I get the same error with AdoptOpenJDK, Zulu and Corretto builds of 11.0.6, so maybe a regression as a result of one of the fixes?

Comment: maybe... try an earlier release: If that works without problems, you're most likely running into the regression that I don't remember the details of.

Comment: 11.0.5 of Zulu appears to work OK, not tested other, but I think they will probably work as well

Answer (score 0):

After some research I discovered that the error is due to a bug (again open) on OpenJDK 11.0.6 [JDK-8237875 (zipfs) Directory Stream entries changed behavior between JDK 11.0.5 and JDK 11.0.6](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK- 8237875)

Liferay for its part has taken steps to resolve, even quickly, through LPS-107983 - OpenJDK 11.0.6 compatibility problem. This LPS is already closed and solves the problem on the 7.x and master branches.

How can we patch the LPS without waiting for the new GA to come out?

The possible solutions are:

1. Downgrade OpenJDK to version 11.0.5;
2. If we have the DXP we are in a position to request support directly from Liferay;
3. If we have the CE we can apply the patch autonomously.

For more info you can read this article https://techblog.smc.it/en/2020-05-01/override-lpkg-come-applicare-fix-a-liferay